# JAVA ¿Como sacar una tercera lista con base a dos listas sin una longitud determinada?

Tags: java, lista

En mi codigo, demuestro como inicie dos listas con cantidad de elementos, pero en sí lo que ocupo
son listas que sea independiente la longitud de ambas.
Y que me compare los valores y si son iguales se pasan a una nueva lista, pero si en mi lista A no tengo
un valor, que la lista B si tiene, se pondría en mi lista como "-valor" o sea con un menos, y de caso contrario
seria "+valor".

```
    [![ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>(); 
     a.add("A");
     a.add("B");
     a.add("C");
     a.add(" ");
     a.add("E");
     a.add("F");
     a.add(" ");
     a.add(" ");
     a.add("I");
     a.add("J");
     a.add(" ");
     a.add(" ");
     a.add("M");
     a.add("N");

     ArrayList<String> b=new ArrayList<String>();
     b.add("A");
     b.add("B");
     b.add("C");
     b.add("D");
     b.add("E");
     b.add("F");
     b.add("G");
     b.add("H");
     b.add("I");
     b.add("J");
     b.add("K");
     b.add("L");
     b.add(" ");
     b.add("N");

     for(int i = 0; i< a.size(); i++){ //analiza los valores del arreglo a
     for(int j = 0; j< b.size(); j++){ //analiza los valores del arreglo b
            if((a.get(i).equals(b.get(j)) && b.get(i).equals(a.get(j))) && (b.get(j).equals(a.get(i)) && a.get(i).equals(b.get(j)))){ //Compara si los valores son iguales.
               System.out.println("\"" + a.get(i) + "\" ");

            }
            else {
              if(!(a.get(i).equals(b.get(j)) && b.get(i).equals(a.get(j))) && (b.get(j).equals(a.get(i)) && a.get(i).equals(b.get(j)))){


                   System.out.println("+" +b.get(i)+ "\"");  


                 System.out.println("-" +a.get(j) + "\"");  

              } 
              } 
                }


}][1]][1]
```

Outputs:
"A" 
"B" 
"C" 
+D"
-M"
"E" 
"F" 
+G"
-M"
+H"
-M"
"I" 
"J" 
+K"
-M"
+L"
-M"
"N"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas utilizando Java 7 puedes utilizar el método **contains** de [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), como lo hago a continuación en tu código:

```
ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>(); 
 a.add("A");
 a.add("B");
 a.add("C");
 a.add(" ");
 a.add("E");
 a.add("F");
 a.add(" ");
 a.add(" ");
 a.add("I");
 a.add("J");
 a.add(" ");
 a.add(" ");
 a.add("M");
 a.add("N");

 ArrayList<String> b=new ArrayList<String>();
 b.add("A");
 b.add("B");
 b.add("C");
 b.add("D");
 b.add("E");
 b.add("F");
 b.add("G");
 b.add("H");
 b.add("I");
 b.add("J");
 b.add("K");
 b.add("L");
 b.add(" ");
 b.add("N");

 ArrayList<String> c=new ArrayList<String>();


 for (String valorA : a){
     if(!valorA.equals(" ")){
         if(b.contains(valorA)){
             c.add(valorA);
         }else{
             c.add("-"+valorA);
         }
     }
 }


 for (String valorB : b){
     if(!valorB.equals(" ")){
         if(!a.contains(valorB)){
             c.add("+"+valorB);
         }
     }
 }


 for (String valorC : c){
     System.out.print(valorC+" ");
 }
```

El primer **for** lo que hace es comparar los valores de la lista **a** con la lista **b**, y los que sean iguales los agrega en la lista **c**, de otra manera los agrega pero con un **-**. Y en el segundo **for** solo agrega a la lista **c** con un **+**, los valores de la lista **b** que no encuentra en la lista **a**. El tercer **for** solo imprime los valores de la lista **c**.

El resultado es el siguiente:
A B C E F I J -M N +D +G +H +K +L

Si intercambias solo los signos en los for's 1 y 2 el resultado sería el siguiente:

A B C E F I J +M N -D -G -H -K -L

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAAAAAAAS!!